# How to use multiple DatePicker controls on one page with different Culture for each DatePicker?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datepicker, winrt-xaml

I would like to have two DatePicker controls on one page. Each DatePicker control should have its own Culture (i.e. one EN one HE).

Can it be done and if so how?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this for both Windows Phone 8 and WinRT XAML, but here is the WinRT XAML answer:

```
<DatePicker CalendarIdentifier="GregorianCalendar" />
<DatePicker CalendarIdentifier="HebrewCalendar" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for Windows Phone 8. I am using the DatePicker control in the toolkit. EitanB